# Can a file be recovered after svn delete?

Tags: svn

I am trying to figure out if we need to reduce the number of developers having svn admin rights.

1 - If a subversion user accidentally deletes and commits the delete of a file or folder, how can the file be recovered?

2 - If the subversion user has svn admin rights, does svn delete executed on the client behave differently (more permanent)?

Target: svn command line client under Red Hat Enterprise Linux (RHEL) 5.2

Comment: Thank you for all the good answers.

I understand anything a svn client does simply makes a new revision and all previous revisions are still accessible.  My mistake was confusing the svn server administrator rights (destructive power) with the svn user permissions (non-destructive).  Just be sure the server is backed up. :-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, the deleted data can be recovered. Simply determine which revision removed the information, and "reverse-merge" the commit. Something like this:

```
svn merge -c -12345 working_copy_path
svn commit working_copy_path
```

The -12345 means "reverse-merge revision 12345".

Note that subversion itself doesn't have any concept of "administrative" users. Users either have or do not have read and/or write permissions to any given path in the repository. Also note that depending on how you access the repository, there may effectively be no authorization at all.

Comment: Mark,

Thank you for your clear concise answer and provided examples.

I had been misinformed about the concept of "administrative" svn users and their dangers.  It sounds like the main danger is from administrators of the svn server, not svn users.  

I understand anything that can be done from an svn client (the server admin rights are not connected to their svn user rights) can be un-done by pointing back to an earlier revision. 

Thanks again,

Answer (score 0):

- 1 - Everything can be undone using SVN. Even a rm (or delete) command can be undone.
- 2 - #1 applies for every users

Answer (score 0):

Just checkout a revision where the file still existed:

```
svn checkout -r <revision> <path to repository>
```

Now you can add the file again.

Comment: See my comment on timdev's answer. Reverse-merging the change preserves the history of the file(s) in question.

Answer (score 0):

A thorough discussion on reverting deletion from the "Version Control with Subversion" book can be found here:

http://svnbook.red-bean.com/nightly/en/svn.branchmerge.basicmerging.html#svn.branchmerge.basicmerging.resurrect